# Why columns value change into NULL when try to update only one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my table which I created in sql server...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses_Table](
[AddressID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[BuildingName] [varchar](300) NULL,
[UnitNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[StreetNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
[StreetName] [varchar](200) NULL,
[Suburb] [varchar](100) NULL,
[POBox] [varchar](20) NULL, 

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Addresses_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[AddressID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Addresses_Table] (BuildingName,UnitNumber,StreetNumber, StreetName, Suburb) VALUES ('mybuilding', '101', '12','Street 1', 'TEST12')
```

When I try to update '**POBox**' column value into '1234' (any value),
*BuildingName*, *UnitNumber*, *StreetNumber*, *StreetName* turn into **NULL** values.
I have attached my sql update query and results of it.

Please help me out to solve this problem....

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (no matter how small the snippet).

Comment: Your SQL/image does not reproduce the problem: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e752de4dfa8848c3620eddc7740e8dcb).

Comment: Why blank out the table name in the error when you have already defined the table schema and name and included data in your script?  The messages suggest that something else is executing for the table you ACTUALLY updated - does it have a trigger perhaps?

Comment: Every column nullable except your identity? You should really seriously reconsider your schema choices.

Comment: @MartinCairney - Found the problem after I read your reply. It was a trigger. Thank you

Comment: @SMor - This isnt the actual table. Just an example table to demonstrate my problem. Anywy thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Good habits are learned and practiced. And you are known by the code you post, not what you claim to do in "real life". Quite frankly, I would scrutinize a person's postings in technical forms like this if I were hiring someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there is a trigger on the table that sets `StreetName` to NULL after the update. This is evidenced by the SSMS output that shows 2 rowcount messages, one when the row is updated directly and the other when the same row is updated by the trigger.

The trigger makes sense from a data perspective since `StreetName` does not apply to a PO box address.

Comment: Yes found it. Like you said it happened because of a Trigger.